# CSV rewriter keeps creating new headers

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, csv

My code is creating the same headers each time, I want it to create one and append the data to a CSV without creating a new header.

[What it looks like in the CSV](https://gyazo.com/5e760afb5ed8408195d1139755269121)

[What I want it to look like](https://gyazo.com/52f08e5fad73d38e82171b189867048b)

```
import csv

with open("Details.csv","a+") as Details:
    w=csv.writer(Details,delimiter=",")

    headers1=["Name","Age","Year Group"]
    line=Details.readlines()
    if line!=["Name","Age","Year Group"]:
        w.writerow(headers1)
    print("Welcome User, to my Topics Quiz!\n-------------------------------
    --------\nYou can choose from 3 different topics:\n  • History\n  •
    Music\n •  Computer Science\n---------------------------------------")
    print("Before we start, we need to register an account.")
    User=input("Enter your name:\n")
    Age=input("Enter your age:\n")
    Year=input("Enter your year group:\n")

    details=[User,Age,Year]
    w.writerow(details)
    Details.close()

with open("UserPass.csv","a+") as Userpass:
    w=csv.writer(Userpass,delimiter=",")
    headers2=["Username","Password"]
    if headers2 not in Userpass:
       w.writerow(headers2)

NewUser=(User[:3]+Age)
print("Great! Your username is set to: {}".format(NewUser))
Pass=input("Enter a password for your account:\n")
userpass=[NewUser,Pass]
w.writerow(userpass)
Userpass.close()
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please read [**Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question) which applies to text format data like csv files, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are opening file in appending mode (https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open), so this `line=Details.readlines()` will always be empty line and your headers will be written every time (code will always get into **if**).

It is similar with other file. So I suggest you first check if file exist, and if not create it and add headers, and remove headers part from `with`:

```
import csv

import os.path
if not os.path.isfile("Details.csv"):
    with open("Details.csv", "a+") as Details:
        w = csv.writer(Details, delimiter=",")
        headers1 = ["Name", "Age", "Year Group"]
        w.writerow(headers1)
        Details.close()

if not os.path.isfile("UserPass.csv"):
    with open("UserPass.csv", "a+") as Userpass:
        w = csv.writer(Userpass, delimiter=",")
        headers2 = ["Username", "Password"]
        w.writerow(headers2)
        Userpass.close()

with open("Details.csv", "a+") as Details:
    w = csv.writer(Details, delimiter=",")
    print("Welcome User, to my Topics Quiz!\n-------------------------------"
          "--------\nYou can choose from 3 different topics:\n  • History\n  • "
          "Music\n •  Computer Science\n---------------------------------------")
    print("Before we start, we need to register an account.")
    User = input("Enter your name:\n")
    Age = input("Enter your age:\n")
    Year = input("Enter your year group:\n")

    details = [User, Age, Year]
    w.writerow(details)
    Details.close()

with open("UserPass.csv", "a+") as Userpass:
    w = csv.writer(Userpass, delimiter=",")
    NewUser = (User[:3] + Age)
    print("Great! Your username is set to: {}".format(NewUser))
    Pass = input("Enter a password for your account:\n")
    userpass = [NewUser, Pass]
    w.writerow(userpass)
    Userpass.close()
```

Comment: Outstanding job! I can see you've put some great effort into helping. Although just one tiny issue, my OCD kind off in this case. In the text file there's a gap between each user and the other stuff, could it be due to me \n at each input line?

Answer (score 0):

There are different problems in your code:

1) Empty line between lines with data in csv file, it happens because of the nonbinary type of opening and can be fixed by adding that arg in open function:

```
w=csv.writer(Details,delimiter=",",lineterminator='\n')
```

2) In your case Details.readlines() method was returning [], because of the a+ type of opening, it's supposed to add lines in the end of file, so pointer is in the end already and we need to return it at the beginning by using that code:

```
line=Details.seek(0)
```

3) Also, we need only first line, so just use readline() method. And after all, your condition should look that way, because of the return type and the fact that there's \n in the end of every line:

```
if line!="Name,Age,Year Group\n":
```

And the full code of that part. Let me know if it works well for you:

```
w=csv.writer(Details,delimiter=",",lineterminator='\n')
headers1=["Name","Age","Year Group"]
line=Details.seek(0)
line=Details.readlines()[0]
print(line)
if line!="Name,Age,Year Group\n":
    w.writerow(headers1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand everything your code is trying to accomplish, but the following will add a row to the `Details.csv` without creating any new headers:

```
import csv
import os

csv_fileheader = "Name", "Age", "Year Group"
csv_filename = "Details.csv"

print("Welcome User, to my Topics Quiz!\n"
      "---------------------------------------\n"
      "You can choose from 3 different topics:\n"
      " • History\n • Music\n • Computer Science\n"
      "---------------------------------------")
print("Before we start, we need to register an account.")
user = input("Enter your name:\n")
age = input("Enter your age:\n")
year = input("Enter your year group:\n")

if not os.path.isfile(csv_filename):  # Create file if it doesn't exist.
    with open(csv_filename, "w", newline='') as csv_file:
        csv.writer(csv_file).writerow(csv_fileheader)  # Put header row in it.

with open(csv_filename, "a+", newline='') as details2:
    writer = csv.writer(details2, delimiter=",")
    writer.writerow((user, age, year))
```

You should consider following the [PEP 8 - Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) recommendations as it will make your code easier for both you and others to read.

Comment: Thank you, I've read through the PEP 8  also used youtube and i find it very useful also i see from your perspective how hard my terrible code can read, about your code, I run it but now there's not headers appearing. Where i just want one when the csv is created.

Comment: When I tested it on an existing file that already had a header and several rows of data in it, the code simply added a new row to the end of the file. If the file didn't already exist, then a file would be created and it wouldn't have a header, so perhaps that's what happened.

Comment: SRD1707: Sorry I don't understand your follow-on question. Which code are you talking about, yours or what's in my answer? What \n in each input ine? Which text file? When do these gaps appear?